# UITableView Group Style Cell background

Tags: iphone, uitableview

my question is simple....

How to get rid of the white background color of cells in Group Style.

I know about clearColor but it just clears the background color of the tableview itself and not the background color of cells.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UITableViewCell` class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a [`backgroundView` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW5). This is typically set to `nil` for normal-stye table views, but for grouped table views it isn't. Try this:

```
if ([ cell backgroundView] != nil ) {
    [[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
} else {
    // Create a view, set its frame to the cell's frame, and set its background
    // color.
}
```

That code will set the cell's background color to red if it's in a grouped table view.

Comment: Well the first part didn't work. So I removed the if statement and the "else" part worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot.